# camel log message with possible nullpointer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I prepare camel route and I want add log message, but on method getHeader in some cases nullpointer is excpected. How to rebuild log message?

```
process(exchange -> {
    LOG.info("Receipt file name for customer ${company.getCompanyId()}: ${exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.OBJECT_NAME, String.class}");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this a bit wrong `LOG.info` is the regular Logger such as log4j, slf4-api etc.

If you want to log a message with details from the Camel message then use Camel's Log EIP: http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html

eg instead of `processor` use `log` instead.

Comment: thank you for comments and how to avoid NPE? I don't want to risk of breaking the process

Comment: Camel versions 2.3+ can use OGNL expressions, which include the `?` null-safe operator. For example: `${company?.companyId}`